# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Where can I get private companies' financials?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/where-can-i-get-private-companies-financials)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there an open data api or service for dates of official government holidays?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/is-there-an-open-data-api-or-service-for-dates-of-official-government-holidays)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I convert from Census 2010 tracts to Census 2000 tracts?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/how-can-i-convert-from-census-2010-tracts-to-census-2000-tracts)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there an open data format for screen/play scripts?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/is-there-an-open-data-format-for-screen-play-scripts)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Captcha in a website with open data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/captcha-in-a-website-with-open-data)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Has any MOOC (Coursera, edX, Udacity or others) publicly released some of their student data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/has-any-mooc-coursera-edx-udacity-or-others-publicly-released-some-of-their)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Getting legal information](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/getting-legal-information)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Set of handwritten, labeled characters](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/set-of-handwritten-labeled-characters)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Congressional Record in electronic form](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/congressional-record-in-electronic-form)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cellular Network database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/cellular-network-database)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Answer (score 2):

The #1 suggestion I have after combing through this set of questions is to focus on:

## Question editing

When a new question comes in, there are a few things to think about.  First, obviously, is if you can answer it.  Second, make sure it's the sort of question that *can* be reasonably answered.  Almost all of the [Ground Rules for Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules) would apply here.  The questions I've read so far have been far too light on details for my taste.  Questions that can't be answered with confidence, should be closed until they are edited into shape.

After the community has given questions **a shot at getting a good answer** or two, the next step is to improve the odds that **answers will be seen to the outside world**.  The two biggest things you can do to help are:

1. Improve question titles, and
2. Create and apply a sensible [tagging scheme](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/what-is-this-sites-tagging-philosophy).