# Are [geospatial] and [gis] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Quoting from [Jon's excellent post](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/187):

> … it's none too clear how questions are divided among [maps](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps), [geospatial](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial), and [gis](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gis).  I suspect they should be synonyms in the context of this site.

What is your opinion? Should [geospatial](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial) and [gis](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gis) be merged? If so, which one should be kept? And what about [maps](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO there's no important difference between `geospatial` and `gis` at this level of granularity. `maps` implies an existing visual representation of the data (as opposed to the data itself) but I don't know if the average user is intending that distinction or not. And I don't know if I personally consider a "map" to be "open data" if the geospatial data behind it isn't open.

TL;DR: merge geospatial and gis.

Comment: I completely agree. Which tag would you suggest we should use?

Comment: I'd be tempted by `spatial`, but out of the above two, `geospatial`.

Comment: Personally I think ```geospatial``` is the way to go. What would be the advantage of spatial in your opinion?