# Are [city] and [municipal] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently we have 27 [city](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) and 14 [municipal](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/municipal) tags. Neither of them has a description.

Is there any difference between them, or are they actually synonyms? If we merge them, which one should we keep?

**Update:** Thanks for the feedback! For now I have merged [municipal](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/municipal) into [city](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city) and created a respective tag synonym. I've also created an initial tag wiki — please feel free to improve it!

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any important distinction between the two. *municipal* is a more general term for *city*, when *city* is taken to connote a certain scale.

I'd vote for *city* as more familiar, with an explanation on the tag wiki that says it stands for all local-government level questions.

That said, I'm skeptical of the value of either tag. How does it help anyone use this site more effectively? I guess I'll try to put my opinions in that regard in the [What is this site's tagging philosophy?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/what-is-this-sites-tagging-philosophy) question.

Comment: To answer your question, I do a lot of work with council (also known as local government, and roughly equivalent to municipal or city) data. Having questions related to that kind of data would certainly be meaningful and helpful.

Comment: @SteveBennett I'm not saying that there shouldn't be questions about cities. Just asking what we use tags for. How do you use tags on the site now? Would questions about, for example, Chicago's open data portal be helpful to your work with your local council data?

Comment: quite possibly, yes. many of the questions I run into with council data are some variation of "how do other councils handle this kind of data". It's hard to say how I use tags. IMHO there are far too few tags, and I don't have enough rep to create new ones, so they don't really work for me (yet).

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for the answer. Also I think you do have enough reputation. [This](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) says you need 150 and at the moment you have 191. So have at it!

Comment: Ok, I will do :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we use "city". I think it's useful to have a tag like this to help look at data that is restricted to a specific level of government, that reflects information about more local elections or issues, or related to city services.